# Changing button content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

So I am doing a little Tic Tac Toe to learn C#. Basically I have 9 buttons and if they get clicked they need to change the content. But if I try x:Name="namename" I get an error. So how can I change the button content?

XAML-Code:

```
<Window Click:Class="FickFackFo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:Click="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FickFackFo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="165,45,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>

        <Button Click="X1" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="50" ClickMode="Press" Background="White"/>
        <Button Click="X2" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="265,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="50" ClickMode="Press" Background="White"/>
        <Button Click="X3" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="50" ClickMode="Press" Background="White"/>
        <Button Click="X4" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="50" ClickMode="Press" Background="White"/>
        <Button Click="X5" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="265,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="50" ClickMode="Press" Background="White"/>
        <Button Click="X6" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="50" ClickMode="Press" Background="White"/>
        <Button Click="X7" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,245,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="50" ClickMode="Press" Background="White"/>
        <Button Click="X8" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="265,245,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="50" ClickMode="Press" Background="White"/>
        <Button Click="X9" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,245,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="50" ClickMode="Press" Background="White"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Behind-Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace FickFackFo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        int round = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void X1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (round == 0 || round == 2 || round == 4 || round == 6 || round == 8)
            {
                Content = "X";
            }
            else if (round == 1 || round == 3 || round == 5 || round == 7 || round == 9)
            {
                Content = "O";
            }

            round++;
        }

        private void X2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (round == 0 || round == 2 || round == 4 || round == 6 || round == 8)
            {
                Content = "X";
            }
            else if (round == 1 || round == 3 || round == 5 || round == 7 || round == 9)
            {
                Content = "O";
            }

            round++;
        }

        private void X3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (round == 0 || round == 2 || round == 4 || round == 6 || round == 8)
            {
                Content = "X";
            }
            else if (round == 1 || round == 3 || round == 5 || round == 7 || round == 9)
            {
                Content = "O";
            }

            round++;
        }

        private void X4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (round == 0 || round == 2 || round == 4 || round == 6 || round == 8)
            {
                Content = "X";
            }
            else if (round == 1 || round == 3 || round == 5 || round == 7 || round == 9)
            {
                Content = "O";
            }

            round++;
        }

        private void X5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (round == 0 || round == 2 || round == 4 || round == 6 || round == 8)
            {
                Content = "X";
            }
            else if (round == 1 || round == 3 || round == 5 || round == 7 || round == 9)
            {
                Content = "O";
            }

            round++;
        }

        private void X6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (round == 0 || round == 2 || round == 4 || round == 6 || round == 8)
            {
                Content = "X";
            }
            else if (round == 1 || round == 3 || round == 5 || round == 7 || round == 9)
            {
                Content = "O";
            }

            round++;
        }

        private void X7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (round == 0 || round == 2 || round == 4 || round == 6 || round == 8)
            {
                Content = "X";
            }
            else if (round == 1 || round == 3 || round == 5 || round == 7 || round == 9)
            {
                Content = "O";
            }

            round++;
        }

        private void X8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (round == 0 || round == 2 || round == 4 || round == 6 || round == 8)
            {
                Content = "X";
            }
            else if (round == 1 || round == 3 || round == 5 || round == 7 || round == 9)
            {
                Content = "O";
            }

            round++;
        }

        private void X9(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (round == 0 || round == 2 || round == 4 || round == 6 || round == 8)
            {
                Content = "X";
            }
            else if (round == 1 || round == 3 || round == 5 || round == 7 || round == 9)
            {
                Content = "O";
            }

            round++;
        }
    }
}
```

I already said everything but it says I should add details so: This is a detail.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set the `sender`s Content property and you can vastly simplify your code by using only one <strike>Command</strike> Event Handler because it will always receive the button firing the event:

**Xaml** (part)

```
...
<Button x:Name="button1" Click="button_Click" Content="X" ...
<Button x:Name="button2" Click="button_Click" Content="X" ...
<Button x:Name="button3" Click="button_Click" Content="X" ...
...
```

**Code behind**

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // break after 9 rounds
    if (round > 9)
    {
        // your code doesn't do anything after round 9 so I'll also just stop as well
        return; 
    }

    // cast object sender to Button class
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    // use modulo to get rid of all those if conditions
    if (round % 2 == 0)
    {
        btn.Content = "X"; // set Button.Content property
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Content = "O"; // set Button.Content property
    }

    round++;
}
```

Comment: Button click event is a routed event. That means you can subscribe to that event handler in a parent grid or window tag. That button_click code is an event handler rather than command.

Comment: @Andy True. I wanted to stick as close to the "WinFormish" approach of the OP to avoid confusion. Personally I'd do this the MVVM way using a Command.